# How to compare data in two CSV tables and save into one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Here's what I have:

```
viacsv.each do |vrow|
  viadate = vrow[10].split(' ')[0]
  viatime = vrow[10].split(' ')[1]
  vianame = vrow[8]
  viaurl = vrow[9]
  csv.each do |row|
    Event.find_or_create_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], eventurl1: row[8], eventname: row[7])
    link = viacsv.find_by(['eventname LIKE ?', "%#{vianame}%"])
    byebug
  end
end
```

at the moment I can't reach the `byebug` statement because I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by' for #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:27697>
```

Any ideas why?

Each row will search `viacsv` for `eventname` in the `vianame` column. If it can't find it it'll skip it, if it can find it, it will put the data inside the `deep_link` column for the row into the EventDB under the `Link_2` column.

Comment: Why are you asking your CSV file for `find_by`? It seems like you're supposed to be referencing a model there. Additionally it's odd that you do a lot of pre-processing on things like `vrow[9]` only to discard that, using the raw values in your `find_or_create_by`.

Comment: I'm still new to this, ITs only ever run once to populate my db table. Its reading two csv files not just one. So i didn't think a model would be used here?

Comment: What Ruby is saying is there's no `find_by` method for a CSV object, which is true. What are you trying to find by event name? Do you mean `Event.find_by(...)`? If you're trying to search the CSV itself, you can't query it that way, you can only use [methods defined in the API](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), no amount of wishful thinking will change this. To find your link you'll need to search through the CSV manually.

Comment: What i was trying to do is search the csv, I didn't mean Event.find_by, i suppose i could try a long winded method of using the event.find_by

Comment: If you're trying to search the CSV then you'll have to iterate through each row, compile an index of names, and write code to search through that using a regular expression or something like it. If you're going to call methods on an object, check the API first to be sure it exists. The CSV documentation I linked to gives you the specifics on what's available.